# Saving loops in R through an SQL Query

Tags: sql, r, loops, save

I  have the following code which is an `SQL` Query in `R`.

I want to loop around this code three times with a new date in the date field (2nd last line of the code).

For example, on the first loop Date = 20170731, on the second loop Date = 20170630 and on the third loop Date = 20170531. I want each loop / query to be saved to a new dataframe.

For simplicity lets say first loop is saved to "First", second loop saved to "Second" and third loop saved to "Third". I don't want the below query to be altered in anyway just look to see how to structure loops / if statements around this code.

Following is what I have:

```
SQLCommandEOM<-data.frame(sqlQuery(myConn, 
"SELECT fc.[FactSet Fund Code], fc.FactsetDate, fc.[Asset Class], fc.[Fund  Manager],
d.Id AS DeskID, d.[Name] AS DeskName, fc.[% Factor Risk], fc.[Predicted Tracking Error],fc.[Portfolio Predicted Beta]  
FROM [PortfolioAnalytics].[Data_Factset].[FundChar] fc 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Data_Axioma.FactSetAccount fsa ON fc.FactsetAccountCode = REPLACE(fsa.Code, '_', '') 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Portfolio p ON fsa.PortfolioId = p.Id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Mandate m ON p.UnderlyingId = m.id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Desk d ON m.DeskId = d.Id 
WHERE IncludesCash = 1 
AND [FactSet Fund Code] IS NOT NULL 
AND [Fund Manager] IS NOT NULL 
AND [Asset Class] IS NOT NULL 
AND FactsetDate =", Date,
"ORDER BY [Predicted Tracking Error] DESC"))
```

Comment: If you just paste together the SQL-query `paste("Select ..", as.character(as.Date(20170737, "%Y%m%d")), "Order By..")` , and it could be that if you use only 1 SQL-query and subset the data frame in R afterwards is faster.

Comment: Think I am getting you here, but sorry to be pedantic do you mind using my exact example for your solution. Hopefully with time I wont need someone to take my hand and show me the code for every solution!